# How do I properly set this variable?

Tags: bash, subtraction

I want to read a epoch time stamp from a file and then compare it with the current epoch time.

The comparison is not working and I get error:

> ./script.sh: line 13: 1559122886- : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")

```
#!/bin/bash
RSTL=restart.log
if [ -f $RSTL ]; then
    while IFS='|' read -r NRST LRST
    do
        echo "NRST is: $NRST"
        echo "LRST is: $LRST"
    done <$RSTL
CTIME=$(date +"%s")
echo "CTIME is: $CTIME"
fi
#LRST=$(date +"%s")
DIFF=$(( $CTIME-$LRST ))
echo "DIFF is: $DIFF"
if [[ $DIFF -gt 86400 ]]; then
    echo "1|GREATER"
    echo "1|$CTIME" > $RSTL
elif [[ $LRST -lt 86400 ]]; then
    echo "LESS THAN"
    echo "2|$CTIME" > $RSTL
else
    echo "1|NEW"
    echo "0|$CTIME" > $RSTL
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mention an undeclared variable in `$((..))` in variable expansion form (like `$var`), it expands to empty string instead of zero, thus the error you get. Don't use variable expansions in arithmetic expansions unless you have to. Change 13th line to following and you're good to go.

```
DIFF=$((CTIME-LRST))
```

Another issue with your script is, you're populating `NRST` and `LRST` in a while loop, and this way those are unaccessible outside the loop. To fix it, replace the while loop with:

```
IFS='|' read -r NRST LRST <"$RSTL"
echo "NRST is: $NRST"
echo "LRST is: $LRST"
```

And don't forget quoting all variable expansions to avoid word splitting.

Comment: Kind of with you here but what change do I need to make ?

Comment: Change 13th line to `DIFF=$((CTIME-LRST))`

Comment: Thanks - this avoids the error but doesn't do the math LRST is being treated as null/zero

Comment: @dross yeah because you're populating it in a while loop, so it is unaccessible from outside.

Comment: That's the exact same thing I wrote in my answer and I even showed you the code how it should look like. So why the down vote ?

Comment: @dross, is `restart.log` a one line file or you want to perform this comparison for each line in it?

Comment: @oguzismail - Its a one liner - I am not reading in the file now instead using awk. Was I creating an array here hence the math error?

Answer (score 1):

In line 12 remove "#" and in line 13 remove "$" from $CTIME and $LRST.

```
#!/bin/bash
RSTL=restart.log
if [ -f $RSTL ]; then
    while IFS='|' read -r NRST LRST
    do
        echo "NRST is: $NRST"
        echo "LRST is: $LRST"
    done <$RSTL
CTIME=$(date +"%s")
echo "CTIME is: $CTIME"
fi
LRST=$(date +"%s")
DIFF=$(( CTIME-LRST )) # Remove $ from $CTIME and $LRST
echo "DIFF is: $DIFF"
if [[ $DIFF -gt 86400 ]]; then
    echo "1|GREATER"
    echo "1|$CTIME" > $RSTL
elif [[ $LRST -lt 86400 ]]; then
    echo "LESS THAN"
    echo "2|$CTIME" > $RSTL
else
    echo "1|NEW"
    echo "0|$CTIME" > $RSTL
fi
exit
```

Comment: Actually Line 12 was test (hence the comment) - I want to read LRST using Line 4. Which appears to work (Line 7 echoes value)

Comment: I suspect that I LRST that is being set on Line 4 isn't being set correctly to do the arithemetic that I am trying below.

Comment: The error you posted is beeing thrown by line 13. Just remove the $ from CTIME and LRST, that should be it.